# How to prove this formula involving binomial coefficients using a combinatorial argument?

Tags: combinatorics

I need to prove the formula $$\left( b + 1 \right)^{a} = \sum_{k = 0} ^{n} \binom{a}{r} b^{r},$$ counting the functions from a set $\{ 1, 2, \dots, a\}$ to a set $\{ 1, 2, \dots, b, b + 1 \}.$

I would like to have some hints on how to do it. Please don't give me the full answer since I have to solve the problem myself.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** try partitioning the functions from $A=\{1,2,3,\dots,a\}$ to $B=\{1,2,3,\dots,b+1\}$ by considering how many functions map $a-r$ elements of $A$ to $b+1$ and the other $r$ to $B\setminus\{b+1\}$.